# Wireless Connection not available until user relogin

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

For some time now I've got problems with my WiFi Connection on a Windows7 notebook.
There are two Windows users set up as Administrators.
When I start the computer and login as userA it states:

> not connected - there are no
>   connections available

Although I normaly can receive 3 wireless networks at home, no network can be found now!

When I then log off and log in as userB, the connection works without problems - switching then to userA again it works there too! So at the moment for userA I first have to switch users to get a working internet connection.

The laptop was working perfectly for about a year - then suddenly the problem arrised!

It's an intern wireless card: intel wifi link 1000 bgn

laptop: Acer Aspire 1810TZ

Windows 7 Home Premium